# SQL: How to query table by value from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables in my CMS. One contains template variables, eg:

```
table: template_variables
||id||contentid||value||
||1 ||3         ||"Some template variable"||
||1 ||4         ||"Another template variable"||
||2 ||5         ||"Some other template variable"||
```

The other table contains contains content and, importantly, has a column for if that content i published or not, eg:

```
table: content
||id||published||value||
||3 ||0        ||"I am not published"||
||4 ||1        ||"I am published"||
||5 ||1        ||"I am published too"||
```

I want to make a query that returns the value of `template_variables` based on whether their associated content is published or not. For example with the above I would like to return the values `Another template variable` and `Some other template variable` as their associated content (4 and 5) is marked as published in the `content` table.

I have tried various queries useing `INNER JOIN` but have had no success, eg:

```
SELECT `value`, `contentid` FROM `template_variables` INNER JOIN content WHERE template_variables.contentid=content.id
```

but have not been able to get this working - either I have the wrong syntax or the results are wrong.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for how to go about this?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a join as you just want to use the content table for reference of published column

```
  SELECT * from template_variables
   Where contentid in
   (select id from content where 
    published =1)
```

Or for better performance use `Exists(..)` as

```
   SELECT * from template_variables t
   Where Exists(select 1 from content c
     Where c.published=1 and 
      t.contentid=c.id)
```